# How to implement a custom ResponseStatus using ServiceStack in combination with a custom REST Api

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I've been using the new ServiceStack API like this:

```
[Route("/me/login/")]
public class LoginRequest : IReturn<LoginResponse>
{
    public string password { get; internal set; }
    public string username { get; internal set; }
}

public class LoginResponse
{
    public string token { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
client.PostAsync(new LoginRequest { username = email, password = password });
```

However, the server is a Django REST Api. So when I type an incorrent password I get the following response:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to login with the given credentials."
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the information in the `non_field_errors` property leveraging the new ServiceStack API? (What should I override?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack Service Clients are only meant to be used for ServiceStack Services, I'd recommend using [ServiceStack's HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) for calling 3rd party services.

The Response DTO to match that JSON would look like:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string[] non_field_errors { get; set; }
}
```

If the response returns a non 200 HTTP Error than you'll need to read the JSON from the error body response instead, e.g:

```
try 
{
    var response = baseUrl.CombineWith("me/login")
        .PostJsonToUrl(new LoginRequest { ... })
        .FromJson<LoginResponse>();
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    HttpStatusCode? errorStatus = ex.GetStatus();
    string errorBody = ex.GetResponseBody();
    var errorDto = errorBody.FromJson<LoginResponse>();
}
```